# How to make a cartoon style custom dialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am wanting to make a colorful cartoon style custom dialog for a game. When I try an look up "custom dialog" for android, all I can see is standard, grey text dialogs where the only custom aspect is the choice of wording. Can someone point me in the right direction.

By the way, this is a dialog to appear in the middle of the pre-existing game screen - not a full screen dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) and pass to constructor any custom view you want.